# what is the best way to upload file with javaee maven

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee

im trying to upload file with fileUpload , i added the jar library ( commons-io-1.4.jar commons-fileupload-1.2.jar ) and configure web.xml by adding filter :

```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filterclass>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filterclass>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
        <param-value>2097152</param-value>
    </init-param>      
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

but i get a build failure , am i doin it right or im missing something else

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What build error do you get? Please _edit your question_ and add these points (don't comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you code is suffering with  dependency error. You need to add version dependency

```
<dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
         <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
       <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
       <version>1.3.1</version>
 </dependency>
```